# Trig substitution in vector calculus

Tags: calculus, linear-algebra, trigonometry

I have  gotten the $$|T'(t)| = \sqrt{0^2+\left(\frac{-48}{12}\sin(4t)\right)^2+\left(\frac{-48}{12}\cos(4t)\right)^2}$$

Can I replace (using trig identity) $${\left(\frac{-48}{12}\sin(4t)\right)^2+\left(\frac{-48}{12}\cos(4t)\right)^2}$$ for $$\left(-\frac {48}{12}\right)^2\cdot 1$$

Is this valid?

My final $$|T'(t)| = \frac{48}{12}$$
Can I use this answer to calculate $K$ which is $\frac {|T'(t)|}{r'(t)}$

Comment: Yes, the trigonometric property is true for every real, in particular for $4t$. But you have a typo (should be $48/12=4$ instead of $48/13$).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, but be careful, your $12$ turned into a $13$, so you should have $$|T'(t)| = \sqrt{\left(\frac{48}{12}\right)^{2}} = 4$$

Comment: Thats a typo, fixed. I was asked to find $$|T'(5\pi / 12)|$$  Is this answer right for the asked input of $5\pi / 12$?

Comment: Yes, what you have works for any value of $t$.